# Open MS Access form or report in same location as when last closed

Tags: forms, ms-access, position, vba, size

I'm kind of a novice at Access and having some difficulty implementing something I saw in another post. [MS-Access: How to open form in same location/size as closed/previous form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3114224/ms-access-how-to-open-form-in-same-location-size-as-closed-previous-form)

I want to open my pop-up forms in the same location they were last closed in and I've created a table (sizpos) to store the 4 attributes for position and size (left, top, width, height) and the name of the form (object) and a unique id number.

I need some help figuring out the VBA code to store the attributes of the open form based on the form name on the close or unload event.  I also need help with the code to retrieve the information from the table for the opening form on the open or load event.

I tried making use of `dlookup` in `me.move` and did not have any success, but may not have been implementing it correctly.

I came up with the following that almost works for the reports.  I just can't figure out how to pull the report's name from the report being opened similar to the `me.name` function in a form.  I've noted those areas with `me.reportname`???

```
Private Sub Report_Open(Cancel As Integer)
Dim l As Long
Dim t As Long
l = Nz(DLookup("Left", "SizPos", "Object = 'me.reportname???'"))
t = Nz(DLookup("Top", "SizPos", "Object = 'me.reportname???'"))
Me.Move Left:=l, Top:=t
End Sub

Private Sub Report_Close()
Dim strSQL As String
strSQL = "UPDATE SizPos SET SizPos.Left = " & Me.WindowLeft & ", SizPos.Top = " & Me.WindowTop & " WHERE SizPos.Object = 'me.reportname???';"
CurrentDb.Execute strSQL
End Sub
```

The below works great for the form.

```
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
Dim l As Long
Dim t As Long
Dim w As Long
Dim h As Long
l = Nz(DLookup("Left", "SizPos", "Object = '" & Me.Name & "'"))
t = Nz(DLookup("Top", "SizPos", "Object = '" & Me.Name & "'"))
w = Nz(DLookup("Width", "SizPos", "Object = '" & Me.Name & "'"))
h = Nz(DLookup("Height", "SizPos", "Object = '" & Me.Name & "'"))
Me.Move Left:=l, Top:=t, Width:=w, Height:=h
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Close()
DoCmd.Save
Dim strSQL As String
strSQL = "UPDATE SizPos SET SizPos.Left = " & Me.WindowLeft & ", SizPos.Top = " & Me.WindowTop & ", SizPos.Width = " & Me.WindowWidth & ", SizPos.Height = " & Me.WindowHeight & " WHERE SizPos.Object = '" & Me.Name & "';"
CurrentDb.Execute strSQL
End Sub
```

Comment: There is no `reportname` property.  Use `Me.Name` to get the report's name.  `Me.Name` is available both in a form or report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `DAO.Recordset` instead of 4 `DLookup` statements to fetch the values for the object's size and position.  You can also use a `DAO.Recordset` to store them later instead of building and executing `UPDATE` and `INSERT` statements.

This is my *sizpos* table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE sizpos (
    id COUNTER PRIMARY KEY,
    obj_name TEXT(255) UNIQUE,
    lft INTEGER,
    tp INTEGER,
    wdth INTEGER,
    hght INTEGER
    );
```

I created a parameter query to fetch stored size and position values for a given form or report name:

```sql
PARAMETERS which_object Text (255);
SELECT s.obj_name, s.lft, s.tp, s.wdth, s.hght
FROM sizpos AS s
WHERE s.form_name=[which_object];
```

I could have saved that as a named query.  But I created a function, *SelectObjectSettings*, to return that statement text.

So during *Form Load*, I can feed the form's name to that query and open a `DAO.Recordset` with the query's result.  Then, if the recordset is not empty, use the recordset's values to set the form's size and position:

```vb
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set qdf = db.CreateQueryDef(vbNullString, SelectObjectSettings)
    qdf.Parameters("which_object").Value = Me.Name
    Set rs = qdf.OpenRecordset
    With rs
        If Not (.BOF And .EOF) Then
            Me.Move Left:=!lft, Top:=!tp, Width:=!wdth, Height:=!hght
        End If
    End With

    Set rs = Nothing
    Set qdf = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing

End Sub
```

Note: If you have a saved parameter query, you can `Set qdf` to that ...

```vb
'Set qdf = db.CreateQueryDef(vbNullString, SelectObjectSettings)
Set qdf = db.QueryDefs("YourQueryName")
```

At *Form Unload*, save the form's size and position:

```vb
Private Sub Form_Unload(Cancel As Integer)
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set qdf = db.CreateQueryDef(vbNullString, SelectObjectSettings)
    qdf.Parameters("which_object").Value = Me.Name
    Set rs = qdf.OpenRecordset
    With rs
        If (.BOF And .EOF) Then
            ' no existing record for this object; create one
            .AddNew
            !obj_name = Me.Name
        Else
            ' a record exists for this object; edit it
            .Edit
        End If
        !lft = Me.WindowLeft
        !tp = Me.WindowTop
        !wdth = Me.WindowWidth
        !hght = Me.WindowHeight
        .Update
        .Close
    End With

    Set rs = Nothing
    Set qdf = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: I have been unable to get this to work successfully.  How are you creating your function?  Ive tried to call the saved query and call the query parameters directly as below, but keep getting Too few parameters. Expected 1.

    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT s.left, s.top, s.width, s.height FROM SizPos AS s WHERE s.object = " & Me.Name)

Comment: If you want to do it that way, you will need to add quotes around `Me.Name` ... `Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT s.left, s.top, s.width, s.height FROM SizPos AS s WHERE s.object = '" & Me.Name & "'")`

Comment: I added an update to show how to use a saved parameter query.

Comment: Thanks very much.  Sorry for all the questions, but I'm learning a lot.  Also, thanks for the initial heads up on me.name working in reports.  I thought that was the case, but on further review, it wasn't working because the name of the report was mispelled in the table.

Comment: You might prefer to adapt the code as generalized procedures which you could then call from the Load and Unload events of any form or report.